# jQuery mobile dialog not working with new page

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog

I have a site built on jQuery Mobile and am trying to get our Terms of Service to open in a dialog.
TOS page is a full page itself (separate URL) and when I link with the dialog reference it simply opens as a new page.
My footer is

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="<?php echo $dataTheme ?>">
<div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a rel="external" href="http://www.trackmaster.com">Full Site</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tosfull.php" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Terms</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/cgi-bin/my_acct_entry.cgi">My Account</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

and my tos.php page is (content stripped for convenience)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="author" content="AXCIS Information Network">
        <title>TrackMaster Terms of Service</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mobiletest.trackmaster.com/styles/mobile/themes/TrackMasterMobile.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mobiletest.trackmaster.com/styles/mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://mobiletest.trackmaster.com/javascript/frameworks/jquery-current.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mobiletest.trackmaster.com/styles/mobile/mobileStyle.css" />
        <!--  Make sure there is a back button on each page  -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
          $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
          $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn= true;
      });
  </script>

        <script src="http://mobiletest.trackmaster.com/javascript/frameworks/jquery.mobile-current.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a"  id="main">
           <div data-role="header">

     <h1 class="headerLink"><a href="/"  class="headerLink"><span class="tmFirst">Track</span><span class="tmSecond">Master</span></a> </h1>
        <a href="/" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
  </div>

           <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="content" class="informationText">
  Blah, Blah, Blah
  </div>


  </div> <!--  this one closes out the content div set in the section header template -->
  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
           <li><a rel="external" href="http://www.trackmaster.com">Full Site</a></li>
           <li><a href="/tosfull.php" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Terms</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://mobiletest.trackmaster.com/cgi-bin/my_acct_entry.cgi">My Account</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <h5 class="copyrightText">&copy; 2013 Axcis Information Network, Inc.</h5>
     <div class="ads">
     <script type="text/javascript"><!--
  google_ad_client = "ca-pub-7303976721498796";
  /* Mobile Bottom */
  google_ad_slot = "5684536575";
  google_ad_width = 320;
  google_ad_height = 50;
  //-->
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
  </script>

     </div>
  </div>
  </div> <!--  this one closes out the page div set in the header template -->
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have tried changing the data role of the TOS page to a dialog but that made no difference.
Am I not understanding the way dialog links can be used (from the docs I thought I could open one from any URL simply by defining the link as a dialog)

Site itself is http://mobiletest.trackmaster.com and it is the Terms link in the footer I am trying to get as a dialog (I don't want to include the content on every page, only when the user asks for it)

Any help appreciated (even pointing out the dumb things I am missing)

Answer (score 0):

You are either missing a `<div>` or they don't match up; you've got two "content" divs.

EDIT: It's probably OK to have one within another, just noting that the `<div data-role="page">` is never closed.  Don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks, Let me fix the layout problems first and see if that corrects the issue

Comment: Nope, still no joy with the missing div close fixed.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear: in your link you have `<a href="/tosfull.php"...` but you then stated that the file is named tos.php.  Which one is wrong? Maybe you have two files?

Comment: When said the TOS page I was using shorthand for tosfull.php :), there is only a single page which is tosfull.php. 
The issue was my disabling Ajax in the header but thanks for finding the borked structure (not sure why I  missed that in my initial testing)

Comment: Actually I'm referring to where it specifically says: "and my tos.php page is (content stripped for convenience)"

Comment: Oops, was supposed to be tos php (no dot), that is why I put the site link in as well

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
The line in the header
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; 
I commented it out and the dialog link works as expected.

was the problem, I am testing it to see what else gets broken when I pull it out :-).
Data role for the TOS page is NOT relevant as loading it as a dialog automatically assigns the dialog data role